# When I clicked button, I want to change editText's text with custom component in adapter

Tags: android, listview, components, listener

I want use a horizontal number picker so I made it custom widget.
In the adapter, When I use custom widget's button click and set count, I want to change `EditText`'s text in adapter.

This is my Custom component

`HorizontalNumberPicker.java`

```
public class HorizontalNumberPicker extends LinearLayout {

    Button plus;
    Button minus;
    EditText num;
    int count;

    OnCustomEventListener mListener;

    public HorizontalNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_number_picker, this);

        plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
        minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);
        num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (num.getText().toString().equals("10")) {
                    if (mListener != null)
                        mListener.onEvent(count);
                    return;
                } else {
                    count = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString()) + 1;
                    num.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    if (mListener != null)
                        mListener.onEvent(count);
                }
            }
        });

        minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (num.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
                    if (mListener != null)
                        mListener.onEvent(count);
                    return;
                } else {
                    count = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString()) - 1;
                    num.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    if (mListener != null)
                        mListener.onEvent(count);

                }
            }
        });
    }

    public interface OnCustomEventListener {
        public abstract void onEvent(int count);
    }

    public void setCustomEventListener(OnCustomEventListener eventListener) {
        mListener = eventListener;
    }

}
```

This is my Custom Adapter

```
private Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
View itemView;

ArrayList<MenuItemData> list;

// Declare Variables
NetworkImageView iv_menu_img = null;
TextView tv_menu_name = null;
TextView tv_menu_price = null;

// Progress dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
int price;

//imageloader using volley
ImageLoader mImageLoader;

HorizontalNumberPicker pick_menu_grid;


public MenuListGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MenuItemData> list, ProgressDialog pDialog) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = new ArrayList<MenuItemData>();
    this.list.addAll(list);
    this.pDialog = pDialog;
    //image loader
    mImageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menulist_grid_item, parent, false);

        iv_menu_img = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_menu_img);
        tv_menu_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_menu_name);
        tv_menu_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_menu_price);
        pick_menu_grid = (HorizontalNumberPicker)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pick_menu_grid);
    } else {
        itemView = (View) convertView;
    }

    // Set the result into ImageView
    iv_menu_img.setImageUrl(url + list.get(position).getImageFilePathIndex(), mImageLoader);

    // Set the results into TextViews
    tv_menu_name.setText(list.get(position).getMenuCHNName());
    tv_menu_price.setText(list.get(position).getMenuPrice());

    //set price to listener
    if(list.get(position).getMenuPrice().equals("")){
        price = 0;
    }
    pick_menu_grid.setCustomEventListener(new HorizontalNumberPicker.OnCustomEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int count) {
            list.get(position).setCount(count);
            price = Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).getMenuPrice());
            tv_menu_price.setText(String.valueOf(price*count));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    pDialog.dismiss();
    return itemView;
}
```

If `HorizontalNumberPicker`'s button clicked -> count is changing (price in `ArrayList`) -> `tv_menu_price.setText(String.valueOf(price*count));` -> `EditText(tv_menu_price)` is changing (in Adapter).

I don't know where can I add or edit this code. Just it doesn't work. How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have to set all data you'r going to change in the dataSet and set the data to the texts like text.setText(dataSet.get(i) blabla). So in your main activity you do like this: adapter.getData().set(i).blabla and then call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after you make changes on the dataSet.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But How can I tried it? I tried ArrayList<item> getData(){return list;} and notifyDatasetChanged. But It doesn't work as well. I can know the data changed just in customAdapter.java so I don't know how can setData in Activity....

Comment: You can do things like this:
ArrayList<item> data = adapter.getData();
Now modify "data" as data will be pointing to adapter.getData(); so any change in data will also change your list in adapter. After all this invoke adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I tried listview.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.getData();
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ...is it correct?

Comment: In data of your adapter you have to set what you want to put to the edit edittext. In on createView you have to do something like edittext.setText(getData(position).get("text")). Now if you want to change the text you call your adapter.getData() and modify it!! Then adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()